# Google Sheets API: Copying multiple sheets data to another seperate worksheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to copy 4 separate sheets (within a single worksheet) onto an already existing worksheet.  I want to be able to copy all of the data on all 4 sheets and copy them over to the secondary sheet with the same 4 tables and also not have the title "COPY OF XXXX".  I dont know if I'm just not looking in the right place in the Dev Sheets API Website but so far i've tried the copyTo method and copyPaste method and can't seem to get it to copy all 4 sheets onto another WORKsheet.  Each of the sheets are going to have 4 different sheet id's of course.  Not sure I'm looking at it right. Just want a second opinion on how I can structure it.  Thanks.